# Azure Devops artifacts feed as upstream source for feed in separate Azure Devops server

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-artifacts, azure-devops-server-2019

There are multiple on-premise Azure Devops 2019 servers within my organization. There's an artifacts feed on server A, where some internal nuget packages are published.

Repository of a project I work on is hosted on server B. I want to use a single Azure Artifacts feed as a source for nuget dependencies for my project, so I would like to setup feed on server A as upstream source for feed in server B. Is there a way to do this? GUI is pretty limited and [documentation wasn't much of a help either](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/how-to/set-up-upstream-sources?view=azure-devops-2019).

Comment: are there within same tenant in your organization/active directory ? you may be able to setup that upstream source.

Comment: @Turbot, they are within the same network, they share active directory, but they are on separate virtual machines. I want set  server A's feed as available upstream source for feeds on server B. Maybe there's a place where I can pass external feed's url in Azure Devops? Something like service connections?

Comment: you can setup from Server B using [set upstream sources from Azure Artifact Feed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/how-to/set-up-upstream-sources?view=tfs-2018#add-an-azure-artifacts-feed-in-your-organization-as-an-upstream-source) - currently only support Universal packages - which you can have cmd/shell step to download , and use the Nuget to reference , i did that for project i working on.

Comment: We can add an Azure Artifacts feed in a different organization within your Azure AD tenant as an upstream source. But you are using Azure DevOps Server and AD instead of Azure DevOps Services and Azure AD. There is currently no such service connection too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid we can not setup feed on server A as upstream source for feed in server B. I totally understand the inconvenience brought to you. 
I suggest you can [create a suggestion ticket](http://%20https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion) in the Developer Community. You can track and vote your suggestion ticket. The product group will review these tickets regularly, and consider take it as roadmap.

As a workaround, you can push your packages to your another server. After that, you can [add an Azure Artifacts feed in your organization as an upstream source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/how-to/set-up-upstream-sources?view=tfs-2018#add-an-azure-artifacts-feed-in-your-organization-as-an-upstream-source).

Comment: thanks for clarification, I'll stick with manually pushing the dependencies and create a suggestion ticket.

Comment: Is there a way to check if this suggestion is implemented?

Comment: link to the suggestion ticket would be nice so I can "+1"